# Filter data from XML with Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a XML-file with data about sequences that contain packages.
I am trying to get an powershell-object containing information about failed packages. (`<PackageSuccess>False</PackageSuccess>`)

Below you find the structure of the XML-file containing sample-data. (Simplified. I hope it is still authentic ...)
Also you find the code to filter the failed packages:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence1</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageName>Package1</PackageName>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageSuccess>True</PackageSuccess>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageName>Package2</PackageName>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageSuccess>False</PackageSuccess>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
    <SequenceMeta>
      <Finished>True</Finished>
    </SequenceMeta>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence2</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageName>Package3</PackageName>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host

$ProcessedSequences = $Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object { $_.SequenceMeta.Finished -eq $true }
$FailedPackages = $ProcessedSequences.SequencePackages.Package | Where-Object { $_.PackageMeta.PackageSuccess -ne "True" }
$FailedPackages
```

The output is the following:

```
PackageName PackageMeta
----------- -----------
Package2    PackageMeta
```

This is somehow OK, but I also want to have the SequenceName in the output like this:

```
PackageName PackageSuccess SequenceName
----------- -----------    -----------
Package2    False          Sequence1
```

I was not able to find a clean solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a calculated property with `Select-Object` and use the `ParentNode` property on the element to walk up to the ancestral node that holds the `SequenceName` element:

```
$FailedPackages |Select-Object PackageName,PackageMeta,@{Name='SequenceName';Expression={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.SequenceName}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did never hear anything about using `$_.ParentNode` before.